# How can I read the header of request to webserver

Tags: delphi, soap, header, webserver

I created a stand alone soap webserver in delphi. I use javascript in the front end to connect to the webserver. I know how to send username and password in the header of each request in javascript but I don't know how to read them in server side by Delphi. Can anyone help me to read the header of the requests?

Comment: What framework/component are you using for the SOAP server? Which header are you sending the credentials in exactly? Need more details about your setup before your question can be answered.